# How do I edit my Windows Desktop Application main dialog in VIsual Studio Commun2019?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019, win32gui

I have to create a Win32 app for a college class.
I created the "Windows Desktop Application" in the create project section of the Visual Studio Community 2019 and it comes already with a standard dialog that can be tested on the go. Problem is: I cannot edit the main dialog. I can create another dialog and edit it but the main one is not accessible in the resource editor. What can I do? I can't find anything on google. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

The main window of the default application created by the "Windows Desktop Application" project template in Visual Studio is not created with a dialog resource. It is created by registering a window class associated with a window procedure, as is standard when creating a desktop application.

You "edit" that window by changing the source code not with a visual editor.

Comment: This is confusing me because in Codeblocks you can create a .rc file and use it while working with win32 apps. So how can i create a .rc externaly and after just include in my program?

Answer (score 1):

**>>I cannot edit the main dialog. I can create another dialog and edit it but the main one is not accessible in the resource editor.**

Yes you can create it, but it has no class and can't be an object.You can try to create a Win32 desktop application, and then create a dialog. When you right-click the dialog box, you will find that you cannot add class. 
[image]

If you want to use this dialog, you can only use this function **DialogBoxW(hInstance, lpTemplate, hWndParent, lpDialogFunc)** to create and show the dialog in your program. The third parameter is the Handle of parent window and it can be NULL. The forth parameter is the callback function.
So we test to call DialogBoxW in WinMain. You can check the picture below. We abandoned the traditional Win32 framework and made the custom window our main window. It work.
[image]

However, it should be noted that windows created in this form are modal, which is not applicable in many scenarios. What you say and what you want to do may be better done with MFC. Win32 does not encapsulate many interfaces like MFC for you to call.

Answer (score 0):

I use Visual Studio 2013 Enterprise, but the procedures will be the same:
1 - On the Solution Explorer, click on the .RC file
2 - In the new window (Resource View), click in Dialog
3 - Double-click the dialog you want to edit...
That´s it...